# Using RSA private key from PuTTY in Filezilla

Tags: ssh, fedora, putty

I have created an RSA private key using PuTTYgen. When I try to use it, I am notified that I can't use this encrypted key in Filezilla, so from the documentation I found that I need to use the Pageant tool. Now the problem is I am using Fedora (the latest version), how can I install Pageant? Is there any equivalent of Pageant out there? I am not good with Linux so I need a GUI method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PuTTY has its own private key file format. If you want to use a key file generated by PuTTYgen, you need to convert it to the OpenSSH key format (which is the standard on Linux and other unix systems). Use the [export command in PuTTYgen](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.62/htmldoc/Chapter8.html#puttygen-conversions).

You'll get a key file, often called `id_rsa` (or `something.id_rsa` if you have several keys). Copy that file to the directory `~/.ssh` on your linux machine (`~` is your home directory). If you call it `~/.ssh/id_rsa`, it'll be picked up automatically, otherwise you'll have to configure ssh to use the right key or to load the key into your agent, both of which are a bit more complicated (and I only know how to do these from the command line). Make sure that the permissions of the `~/.ssh` directory and the `id_rsa` file are appropriate: `~/.ssh` must be writable only by you (and should be readable only by you); `~/.ssh/id_rsa` must be readable and writable only by you.

The Linux equivalent of Pageant is `ssh-agent` or some other keyring program, but that's not what you need here.

Comment: I did what you said when i tried to login from terminal using `ssh` it worked but `FileZilla` is not picking the key i guess. It is not simply loging in.

Comment: After generating the keys and put it in place i have used `ssh-add` to add the key to keyring and it worked after that. But i have to do this everytime i log in so is there a way i can make this happen automatically everytime i log in ?

Comment: @Deepak How do you connect to the Linux system? Through PuTTY or directly on the console? If on the console, what desktop environment (e.g. Gnome, KDE, …) do you use? (Where to do this at login time varies by distribution, and I'm not familiar with Fedora, so it may be best if you ask a new question — be sure to indicate your desktop environment.)

Comment: I am using Fedora and I am using Filezilla to sftp into the remote server. I think i will ask this as a new question.